# Отследить событие во вложенном компоненте Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Начинаю разбираться с vue и столкнулся с трудностью требующей пояснения.

У меня есть компонент "Content", в который вложен компонент "Page1". В Page1 есть текстовое поле, и мне нужно как-то отследить его изменение на уровне "Content.

Content:

```
import { createComponent, reactive, toRefs, onMounted, ref, watch } from "@vue/composition-api";
import Page1 from "../Page1/App.vue";

export default createComponent({
    components: {
        Page1
    },
    methods: {
        check: function (event) {
            console.log("its change"); // не работает
        }
    }
});
```

Page1:

```
<template>
    <div>
       <div><imput v-on:change="check"/></div>
    </div>
    </template>
```